How to switch camera that 3D audio works?
For video it works fine to put markers in timeline and bind cameras to them. But this does not work for surround sound. I suspect a bug, but perhaps I do something wrong.
My test setup for 7.1 sound is very simple. I have a camera CAM at the origin and the speakers around it. Just like this:
LF  C  RF
L  CAM R
LB     RB

All the speakers play one after the other for one second. Rendering Audio and checking audio in Audacity gives what I expect.
But when I extend the setup like this, it does not work:
LF1  C1  RF1     LF2  C2  RF2
L1  CAM1 R1      L2  CAM2 R2
LB1      RB1     LB2      RB2

Again, all the speakers play one after another, all the ..2-speakers after the ..1-speakers. And I added a marker for CAM1 at frame 1 and a marker for CAM2 at frame 168 (7 speakers * 1 second each * 24 fps).
The cameras switch. Speakers ..1 are all correct in the audio file, but speakers ..2 get mixed down to channel 6 (=right direction of listener). It seems to be obvious that CAM1 gets the sound.
In my much more complicated project that problem seems to have more aspects. Sometimes direction and distance seem to work in part, sometimes not.
What can I do to get this work?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Using only one camera jumping at frame 168 from left to right position leads to correct sound in regard of channels, but audio volume is wrong for some channels.
